# KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED - Kerberos failing, trouble ascertaining SPN issue

Tags: http, authentication, iis, active-directory, kerberos

To start with, I'm not a network guy...but there is no network guy, and I'm responsible for a web server now, so I've had a lot to learn.  I'm trying to get Kerberos working (NTLM works fine) and first wound up with 401 "The target principal name is incorrect" errors when trying to authenticate.  I started Kerberos logging, and have this more detailed error:

```
The Kerberos client received a KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED error from the server 
myserver$. The target name used was HTTP/myserver.na.mysite.com. 
This indicates that the target server failed to decrypt the ticket 
provided by the client. This can occur when the target server principal 
name (SPN) is registered on an account other than the account the target 
service is using. Ensure that the target SPN is only registered on the 
account used by the server. This error can also happen if the target 
service account password is different than what is configured on the 
Kerberos Key Distribution Center for that target service. Ensure that the 
service on the server and the KDC are both configured to use the same 
password. If the server name is not fully qualified, and the target domain 
(NA.MYSITE.COM) is different from the client domain (NA.MYSITE.COM), 
check if there are identically named server accounts in these two domains, 
or use the fully-qualified name to identify the server.
```

Then I did setspn -X to see if there were duplicate SPNs, nope.  I don't really see what the problem is here, it's already using the fully qualified server name as the target.  Any ideas on where to look or what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Check the below setting:

1)Select the site from the iis and check that windows authentication is enabled and anonymous is disabled.

2)In order to set up Kerberos for the site, make sure “Negotiate” is at the top of the list in the providers section.

[image]

3)client and the server domain name is the same.

4)Modify IIS enabling UseKernelMode and useAppPoolCredentials

5)Create SPN for the host address for which you are going to use.

6) Configure this service to the application pool used to execute your application.

For more detail, you could refer [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/) how to set up the Kerberos Authentication in iis.